# Why will this go into an infinite loop if it runs more than 11 iterations of the program?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

The program works like a charm until I change the for loop i to i = 0; i < 11 *I want it to be employees*; i++
If i goes above 10 it goes into an infinite loop for some reason and I don't know why.
I need this to go for 22 iterations, or more specifically, the amount of employees.

```
int main()
{

string pairs[22][22] =
{

    { "Mo", "Filippo", "AJ", "Zac", "Alex", "Brandon", "Alec", "Devon", "Anita", "Ariel", "Shannon", "Matt", "Reid", "Connor", "Austin", "Alan", "Chelsea", "Michelle", "Taylor", "Spencer", "Laura", "Marcos" }
};

int employees = 22;

int paired;

int randNum;

bool alreadyPaired;

bool stopCounter;

    //If this is i < 11 or anything higher it will go in an infinite loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        paired = 0;
        while (paired != employees)
        {
            do
            {
                randNum = rand() % employees;
            } while (pairs[0][randNum] == pairs[0][i]);

            alreadyPaired = false;

            for (int a = 1; a < employees; a++)
            {
                if (pairs[a][i] == pairs[0][randNum])
                {
                    alreadyPaired = true;
                }
            }
            if (alreadyPaired != true)
            {
                int counter2 = 1;
                stopCounter = false;

                while (counter2 < employees && stopCounter != true)
                {
                    if (pairs[counter2][i] == "" && pairs[counter2][randNum] == "")
                    {
                        stopCounter = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter2++;
                    }
                }
                if (counter2 < employees)
                {
                    pairs[counter2][i] = pairs[0][randNum];
                    pairs[counter2][randNum] = pairs[0][i];
                }
            }
            paired = 0;

            for (int a = 0; a < employees; a++)
            {
                if (pairs[a][i] != "")
                {
                    paired++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < employees; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < employees; j++)
        {
            cout << pairs[j][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `The program works like a charm until I change the for loop`  then don't change the for loop

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. What happens when you step through it?

Comment: @clcto I'd guess UB, as soon going out of bounds with the `[]` operators somewhere. It could even switch off your fridge ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check Knuth's shuffle algorithm (it will help you allot).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

At a first glance, you have a problem when trying to pair from 1 to less then 22 .
You will have the problem "solved" for 21 (or 20 since 21 is not pair-able) instead of 22 .

The algorithm itself pairs 2 entities, meaning the amount of i increments needed should be 11 (22/2).
However the last loop (i=11) cannot be done since a part of your program only takes into account  21/2  = 10 entities.

Your program should enter infinite loop no even if you put 8 employees and make the i go up to 4.

I cannot pinpoint exactly where in your code you made this mistake , but as a rule of thumb, be very careful when starting counters from 1 instead of 0.